# Share data between scripts?

Tags: scripting, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to create a scoring system. I have 4 buttons with 4 different but similar scripts and want to share 1 GUI Text for the scores. Example Code:

```
var something : Sprite;
var SpriteRenderer : SpriteRenderer;
var score : int = 0;
var guiScore : GUIText;

function OnMouseDown () {
    if(SpriteRenderer.sprite == something) {
        score += 1;
        guiScore.text = "Score: " = score;
    }
}
```

Right now, if I pressed a button and got a point then I pressed a different button the score would start from 0 again. How can I share data something like static variables but different scripts? I know this sounds a bit noobie but any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static variables won't appear in the inspector so you can't assign the GUIText in the inspector (thanks for making me find out). So try using `GetComponent` instead:

```
// make a variable of type GUIText
var guiScore: GUIText;

// assign the gameobject in the inspector
var staticObject: GameObject; 

// Again I don't know the name of your script, so I'll name it StaticScript
// get the script
StaticScript scr = staticObject.GetComponent(StaticScript); 

// assign local GUIText with the one from above
guiScore = scr.guiScore;
```

This way you have already shared 1 GUIText for all other scripts.

However you said:

> Right now, if I pressed a button and got a point then I pressed a
>   different button the score would start from 0 again

Doesn't that mean something is wrong with the `score`, not the `GUIText`?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean sorry

Comment: Try out the code above the separator first, change your `var score` into `public static var score`. Then in the other scripts get the value by `[scriptname].score`.

Comment: The thing is I need to share the GUI text's data between scripts not the score because it won't be able to be shown in the inspector

Comment: Then do the same with your GUIText, make it static.

Comment: How can I apply the GUI text in the inspector if it's static

Comment: I tried adding var targetscript: Staticscript var guiScore : GUIText: function Start () { guiScore = targetscript.guiScore} but it still doesn't work. Sorry it doesn't let me format my code properly

Comment: It's ok, it's still readable :) No you can't do it like that, because your script cannot recognize other scripts automatically. You have to assign the game object of the script in the inspector in order to get the script. That's why I used `GetComponent`.

Comment: :( I don't have enough reputation to use the chat because this is getting really long and I'll try that tomorrow thanks

Comment: Yeah it's fine :) Just a suggestion, you should edit your question instead, append what you've done and what's not working. I'll update my answer accordingly. Comment here when you've updated your question, because I will not be notified of it.

Comment: ok I tried it today but its just not working! The score is just restarting every time I press a different button but would resume if I press the same button again. I just want it to be like static variables.

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to do here. As stated in my answer, if the `score` is reset to 0, doesn't that mean something is wrong with the `score`? And it's really uncommon to share GUI Text across scripts, because what's important in the GUI Text is the data you want to display, which is `score` in your case, right? Then why can't you just share the `score` and leave the GUI Text in 1 script?

Comment: thanks you very much! All I had to do was `var targetscript : Button;` then `function OnMouseDown () { targetscript.score += 1; targetscript.guiScore.text = "Score: " + targetscript.score;`